# Problem with Json Format data Binary FLASK PYTHON

Tags: python, json, flask

am in a problem:

How can I convert a string to json. I have tried many ways and none have worked for me. I have used:

Json.loads () Json.load () Split ()

and none of them have worked for me. There seems to be a problem in the json format.

I want to extract data from that string, but I can't handle it because I can't give it the json or dictionary format to be able to manipulate it. It only gives me the information all as a single joined string.

my code:

```
from flask import Flask, request,jsonify
from flask import request
import json



app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/products', methods=['POST'])


def some_function():

    data1 = request.data
    data2= data1.decode("utf-8")

    print(data1)  #Raw Data
    print(data2)  #Data Decode
    print(json.loads(data2)) 
    
 
    return "hi"



if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(host='192.168.1.1',debug=True, port=1000)
```

This is the error that the console gives me when executing the program:

```
192.168.1.117 - - [13/May/2021 09:03:14] "POST /products HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Black Meza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\Black Meza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Black Meza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Black Meza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Black Meza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Black Meza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Black Meza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Black Meza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Black Meza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Black Meza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Black Meza\Desktop\Products_Flask\app.py", line 18, in some_function
    print(json.loads(data2))  #Data Decode
  File "C:\Users\Black Meza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Black Meza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 335 (char 334)
```

If I remove from my code  ***print(json.loads(data2))*** and I run the code again console showme:

```
b'{"Protocol":"jsonTS","sId":"0053003C3438510935383135","Packets":[{"Id":30117,"Type":"UploadPumpTransaction","Data":[{"DateTime":"2021-05-10T16:19:48","Pump":1,"Nozzle":1,"Transaction":60858,"UserId":1,"Volume":9.01,"Amount":10.00,"Price":1.11,"TotalVolume":0,"TotalAmount":0,"DateTimeStart":"2021-05-10T16:19:32","TCVolume":0}]}]}\r\x00'
{"Protocol":"jsonTS","sId":"0053003C3438510935383135","Packets":[{"Id":30117,"Type":"UploadPumpTransaction","Data":[{"DateTime":"2021-05-10T16:19:48","Pump":1,"Nozzle":1,"Transaction":60858,"UserId":1,"Volume":9.01,"Amount":10.00,"Price":1.11,"TotalVolume":0,"TotalAmount":0,"DateTimeStart":"2021-05-10T16:19:32","TCVolume":0}]}]}
```

any way to have the data in Json or dictionary format and not in string format?
I want to extract the data to save it to a database.
In string format I cannot work it since everything is packed in a single string,

Comment: What is generating this request to your code?  There's a null byte at the end, it would probably be better to fix this at the requesting end as that byte certainly does not belong there.

Comment: @jasonharper  The data in json comes from an electronic device that acts as a client. My program in flask acts as a server that extracts the data in json and sends it to a database.
This electronic device sends data in json format every 2 minutes to my flask application.
I can't change anything in that electronic device, it already comes that way from the factory.

Comment: Ok, then apply `.rstrip("\x00")` to the data before trying to apply `json.loads()`.

Comment: @jasonharper   {'Protocol': 'jsonTS', 'sId': '0053003C3438510935383135', 'Packets': [{'Id': 30117, 'Type': 'UploadPumpTransaction', 'Data': [{'DateTime': '2021-05-10T16:19:48', 'Pump': 1, 'Nozzle': 1, 'Transaction': 60858, 'UserId': 1, 'Volume': 9.01, 'Amount': 10.0, 'Price': 1.11, 'TotalVolume': 0, 'TotalAmount': 0, 'DateTimeStart': 
'2021-05-10T16:19:32', 'TCVolume': 0}]}]}

Comment: @jasonharper It's what the console gives me.
It has become a dictionary, but I still cannot access the data.

Comment: @jasonharper  I was already able to input and extract the data, I was trying to access the dictionary data badly. THANK YOU SO MUCH .
Pd: What does "\ x00" mean at the end of my json data?